# Why does f[set_]:=AppendTo[set,5] not work when applying f to a set?

Tags: function-construction, warning-messages, variable-definitions

The following code works

```
ccc = {};

AppendTo[ccc, 5];
ccc
```

and gives the output `{5}`

However, the following code does not work:

```
ccc={};
cc[emptySet_] := AppendTo[emptySet, 5]
cc[ccc]
```

Instead giving the error "AppendTo: {} is not a variable with a value, so its value cannot be changed."

**Why does the second way not work?**

- From the error I'm guessing the definition of `ccc` is being substituted for for `ccc`, which is not a variable.
- I imagine this is probably me just defining the function incorrectly, with some trivial error (maybe I need a hold or a condition something)

Comment: Look up the difference between passing by value vs passing by reference. In WL you are not passing the list *itself*, but rather *just* the values of the list. In this case you need to pass by reference

Comment: What you want is: `cc[emptySet_] := Append[emptySet, 5]`and not `AppendTo`.

Comment: Just do `cc[Unevaluated@ccc]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To expand upon my comment, in order to *pass by reference* you can use `Hold`. So for instance:

```
In[1]:= foo[Hold[x_], val_] := AppendTo[x, val];

In[5]:= x = {};

In[6]:= foo[Hold@x, 2]

Out[6]= {2}

In[7]:= x

Out[7]= {2}
```

If you pass a held variable, this has the effect of passing by reference as opposed to by value, so we have access to the variable `x` rather than the data that `x` holds.

Comment: Or, you could add `SetAttributes[cc, HoldFirst];` to the OP's code.

Comment: Thank you. I knew what what happening I just wasn't clear how to use Hold (or unevaluated or something else) to fix it.

Comment: That's a good point. It is much more *visually* appealing in the code to not have to pass a bunch of variables as held. Though, I suppose one could argue that it is nice to explicitly `Hold[var]` the variables that need to be held to distinguish between what is reference vs value

Answer (score 5):

According to `AppendTo` [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AppendTo.html):

> AppendTo[x,elem] is equivalent to x=Append[x,elem].

When you use `AppendTo[{}, 1]` Mathematica can't evaluate `{}=Append[{},1]`. The solution is to give the variable's name to `AppendTo` and it'll figure it out. That's why Mathematica has something like `Hold_sth`.

The code below will raise error because when you write `f[l1]`, Mathematica will replace variable's name with it's value and that makes the problem:

```
l1 = {};
f1[l_] := AppendTo[l, 1]
f1[l1]

(*Out: ERROR *)
```

### Solution

You can do it in different ways, one natural way is to say to your function don't replace names with values:

```
l2 = {};
f2[l_] := AppendTo[l, 1]
SetAttributes[f2, HoldAll];
f2[l2]

(*Out: {1} *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate the answer.